# How do I edit the placeholder for a upload file widget in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to edit either of the text placeholders of jQM's upload file widget?
I would like to change "Choose file" to "Upload CV"

```html
<head> <!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head
<body>

                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="cv" value="cv" accept=".pdf" placeholder="Hello" style="padding-top: 1.4vh;border-radius: 0;height: 5.6vh;margin: 0;">
                                
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use title in input field input type="file" title ="file"